# NSObject's category is available for every NSObject subclass even without any import of this category's .h file anywhere

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-category

**Background.**

Please consider the following steps:

1) In Xcode create a new "Single View Application".

2) Create a category NSObject+Extension.h and .m files:

```
// .h
@interface NSObject (Extension)
- (void)someMethod;
@end

// .m
@implementation NSObject (Extension)
- (void)someMethod {
    NSLog(@"someMethod was called");
}
@end
```

3) Ensure that `NSObject+Extension.m` file is included into a main target.

4) Add the following line to AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [[NSString new] performSelector:@selector(someMethod)];

    return YES;
}
```

5) Ensure that `#import "NSObject+Extension.h` line **does not exists** anywhere in the app!

6) Run Application.

The output is

```
2013-08-27 04:12:53.642 Experimental[32263:c07] someMethod was called
```

---

**Questions**

1. I wonder if there is no any #import of this category anywhere in the app, **how is it even possible** that NSString does still have NSObject+Extension available? This behavior makes me feeling very bad about every Objective-C category I declare because I want the categories I declare to be available **only in the scopes** they are declared within. For example, I want NSObject to be extended by `Extension` only in some class but not in the whole app because its globalspace becomes "polluted" otherwise.
2. Is there a way to avoid this behavior? I do want my categories to work only when I explicitly import them, not when I just have them linked to a target I use to run.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> I wonder if there is no any #import of this category anywhere in the app, how is it even possible that NSString does still have NSObject+Extension available? This behavior makes me feeling very bad about every Objective-C category I declare because I want the categories I declare to be available only in the scopes they are declared within. For example, I want NSObject to be extended by Extension only in some class but not in the whole app because its globalspace becomes "polluted" otherwise.

There are no namespaces on Objective-C objects.  If you declare that a class has a method (whether via a category or on the primary `@interface`) then *every* instance of that class will have that method.

The way that Objective-C deals with "private" methods is by choosing not to tell other people about the methods in question (which is accomplished by not `#import`-ing the file that declares those methods).  This, coupled with `-Wundeclared-selector` (warn if you use a selector that the compiler doesn't know about) is about as good of a guard as you're going to get.

But regardless, if you compile the .m file into your final binary, the method *will* exist, even if no one else "knows" about it.

> Are there way to avoid this behavior? I do want my categories to work only when I explicitly import them, not just when I have them linked to a target I use to run.

Yeah, use `-Wundeclared-selector`, and Xcode will warn you.

Answer (score 4):

Including the header just makes it so the compiler knows about it. It compiles it regardless because xCode compiles every file included in a target. At runtime, the method will be there, so even if you didn't include it for compile time checking, the object will still respond to that category method.